# checking if a function is injective without the so called 'horizontal line'

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

is there any other way to just check, not prove, if a function is injective without this horizontal line test? I could not find any other ways online...

Comment: It really, really depends on the kind of function you want to test for injectivity and what you know about it. Do you have a special instance in mind?

Comment: What is this new would-be-pedagogical invention "the parallel test" ? This is not mathematical at all ...

Answer (score 0):

A function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is injective (on $[a,b]$) iff $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is (strictly) monotone on $[a,b]$.

Also, a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is surjective iff $Im(f)=I$ (the image matches the codomain).

Comment: Your characterization of an injective function is obviously false.

Comment: To illustrate the remark of @NeedForhelp consider $f$ defined on $[0,2]$ by $f(x)=\begin{cases}x &  \ \text{ for}0<x<1\\3-x & \ \text{ for} 1 \leq x \leq 2\end{cases}$ It is injective  without being neither continuous nor monotonous. You should erase your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's when we see that the graph of the function only go up or down. Because if not, then we'll easily find 2 distint point with the same y-corrdinate. Also it must be continuous in R.

Comment: **If** a real-valued function $f$ is **continuous** and injective then it's true that it is monotonic. However if $f$ is not continuous that's not the case in general.

Comment: @Lê Đức Minh As you are new on this site, it is maybe difficult for you to situate the level, but surely it is above "familiar sentences" that you could possibly use with a young student of 15-16 years who begins with curves and has difficulties with formal mathematics.